# Loading XPCOMM object

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm writing a Firefox extension with a Panel.
In that panel I have a button launching Notepad;
In the bootstrap.js I have this:

```
const { classes: Cc, Constructor: CC, interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu,
        results: Cr, manager: Cm } = Components;
```

I added this:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
```

In the main.js I have this:

```
panel.port.on("openNotepadd", function(){


    try{

        var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
        console.log('1'); // Never got here

        file.initWithPath("c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe");

        // create an nsIProcess
        var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
        process.init(file);

        var args = [];
        process.run(false, args, args.length);


    }catch(e){
        alert(e.message);
    }

});
```

I don't get any error, just nothing happens. What is wrong with those codes?

Comment: Don't use `nsIProcess`, instead use `child_process` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_child_process#Using_child_process_in_non-jpm_extensions

Comment: @ Noitidart As mentioned in the codes, never got passed "var file = ..."

Comment: With child_process you don't need nsifile but ill post solution on how to get a nsifile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a `nsIFile` do this:

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm');
var file = new FileUtils.File('C:\\blah.png');
```

Avoid it though, nsIFile is not as main thread friendly as `OS.File` and `child_process`

Comment: @DanielH try now, i had type on in the path to FileUtils.jsm

Comment: @ Noitidart I don't understand what you meant by "i had type on in the path to"

Comment: @DanielH i mean "typo" try it again it will work. Before I had `resources:` but there is no plural, it should just be `resource:`

Comment: LOL, I don't know if it's within the spirit of new year's eve, but you didn't post it in plural, see your post it says "Cu.import('resource://gre".
Anyway I managed to find the problem and it's should be:
require('chrome').Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm');
I'm granting you the points since you put efforts by trying to help and pointing me to the right direction.
Thanks.

Comment: Oh shoot! Totally overlooked that, yeah to include Cu you need to put at the top of your addon `var {Cu, Ci} = require('chrome');` then you can do the `Cu.` stuff. Nice job there!